# Hide communities page is too narrow

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, hidden-communities

In the user profile site settings section all subsections except "Hide communities" use full width of regular content area. E.g.:

[Preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current):

> [image: Preferences]

[Flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair):

> [image: Flair]

[Hide communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current):

> [image: Hide communities]

Can we please expand this area to full width as for other related pages?

Comment: That page seems to be using Stacks all the way. There is a `div` under the div#mainbar that has a class `wmx5`. That needs to be `wmx8` to have that container use 8 columns instead of 5. The other pages from your example don't seem to be on the Stacks Design system so I can't verify if that is the way to achieve full width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time goes, design changes, developers fire...

Today's hidden communities page looks similar with the others:

> [image]

> [image]